# Resolving named registration using Unity 2 in DefaultControllerFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, unity-container, controller-factory

I have an issue with resolving named registrations of registered types in Unity 2 using ASP.NET MVC 3 with DI set in DefaultControllerFactory.

In one assembly I have defined Unity container with registration types and named registrations

```
public class VisUnityContainer : UnityContainer
{
    public IUnityContainer RegisterVisComponents()
    {
         // register types
         this               
             .RegisterType<ICompanyService, CompanyService>()
             .RegisterType<ICompanyService, TestCompanyService>( "2" );
    }
}
```

and in my MVC project I have inherited DefaultControllerFactory i am resolving types and passing VisUnityContainer

```
public class UnityControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer unityContainer;

    public UnityControllerFactory( IUnityContainer unityContainer )
    {
        // set contracts
        if( unityContainer == null )
            throw new ArgumentNullException( null, "Unity container is not initialized." );

        // set associations
        this.unityContainer = unityContainer;
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance( RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType )
    {
        // set contracts
        if( controllerType == null )
            throw new HttpException( 404, String.Format(  "The controller for path '{0}' could not be found or it does not implement IController.",
                     requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path ) );
        if( !typeof( IController ).IsAssignableFrom( controllerType ) )
            throw new ArgumentException( String.Format( "Type requested is not a controller: {0}", controllerType.Name ) );

        // action result
        IController controller;

        // company law
        string companyLaw = String.Empty;

        // set user properties
        if( Thread.CurrentPrincipal != null &&
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name != null &&
            !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name ) )
        {
            // set culture for law of companies region
            CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo( Profile.GetCurrent().CompanyState );

            // set language
            CultureInfo uiCultureInfo = new CultureInfo( Profile.GetCurrent().UserLanguage );

            // set dates etc.
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;

            // get proper resource file
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = uiCultureInfo;

            // set company law
            companyLaw = Profile.GetCurrent().CompanyLaw;
        }

        try
        {
            // resolve container
            controller = this.unityContainer.Resolve( controllerType, companyLaw ) as IController;
        }
        catch( Exception )
        {
            // throw exception
            throw new InvalidOperationException( String.Format( "Error resolving controller {0}", controllerType.Name ) );
        }

        // action end
        return controller;

    }
}
```

The problem is with line

```
controller = this.unityContainer.Resolve( controllerType, companyLaw ) as IController;
```

While companyLaw is equal 2 it doesn't resolve named registration TestCompanyService, but always CompanyService. If I also set CompanyService with some named registration, it throws an error saying it can't resolve a type.

Also, if I try manually to resolve a type like

```
var test = this.unityContainer.Resolve<ICompanyService>( companyLaw );
```

It returns the correct type.

Does anybody have an idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
Container.Resolve(type,string)
```

and

```
Container.Resolve<T>(string)
```

aren't different methods.

Resolve(string) is actually an extension method that, internally, calls Container.Resolve(type,string).

Looking at the code, is "controllerType" a class or interface?  If "controllerType" is a class (CompanyService) rather than an interface (ICompanyService) it will always resolve to CompanyService.  It would also explain why it errors when you try to

```
Resolve(controllerType,"2")
```

because what you're actually saying here is:

```
container.Resolve(typeof(CompanyService),"2");
```

which doesn't exist.

This would also explain why it works when you call:

```
container.Resolve<ICompanyService>("2");
```

Because you're setting the correct interface here

So, short answer:

I think you're passing the concrete class type rather than the interface to Unity.  Should be fairly easy to check.

Comment: In this actual example, controllerType is a ASP.NET MVC Controller class. Concrete, I am passing CompanyController which has ICompanyService passed in as constructor's parameter.

Comment: So controllerType is a CompanyController?  If so then that is the problem.  you need to resolve by interface, notconcrete type.  If you resolve by concrete type you'll only ever get an instance of that concrete type.