# Can I use Ninject Modules in any way in constraining the resolution of a request

Tags: ninject, ninject.web.mvc

In our web project we are using Ninject. Now we are adding plugins to our application. We want plugins to be able to add their own bindings. Ninject modules seems like a logical solution to this problem.

However, I don't see any guidance on how to avoid the following problem. What if a plugin adds a binding to an interface that already had a binding. Now the DependencyResolver will throw an exception when trying to resolve that interface.

I'm trying to make a change to our DependencyResolver that doesn't require rewriting all of the binding statements we've already written in the main application. I don't want a plugin to be able to break my main application. If a plugin needs to apply constraints to make it's bindings work then it is its responsibility.

So here's what I want.

1. A plugin would not be able to break the core app or another plugin because it added a binding.
2. It should not be necessary for any change to be made to core application or another plugin when I want to add a new plugin with its own bindings
3. Where there are multiple instances to choose from it should do the "logical" thing. The core app should get the instance it always would have gotten in the absence of the new plugins. The plugin should get the instance it specifically bound.

It seems like I should be able to override the resolving methods of StandardKernel so that it can implement these rules. It seems like knowing what module a binding was a part of would help resolving. But I can't find module or module name as part of the context, request, bindinginfo, etc.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue. I don't see that Ninject seems to answer what seems like a very obvious need for a modular system. A new module shouldn't be able to break an app. (It should only be able to "break" itself.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at [Ninject.Extensions.ChildKernel](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.childkernel). You could create a ChildKernel per plug-in and then load the plugins' module in their own ChildKernel.

This means that a plugin cannot rely on the bindings of another plugin, but a plugin may rely on the bindings of the Parent Kernel (root / application kernel). So you can provide certain types/services to the plugins.

By the way, if the implementation of Ninject.Extensions.ChildKernel does not match your needs, you might very well choose to implement your own extension. It's not that much code (see [ChildKernel source](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.childkernel/tree/master/src/Ninject.Extensions.ChildKernel))

Comment: Thanks we did look at ChildKernel briefly. We should have looked at the code. You are right. It looks very simple and we can either use as is, or write something custom that borrows ideas from that extension. Thanks.

Comment: Shoot. After pursuing this ChildKernel I remembered why we abandoned it in the first place. Within the app (using MVC) the DependencyResolver doesn't have access to the ChildKernels. So when it attempts to find a binding for a controller that is in a plugin, it can'f find it. Perhaps there is a way to modify the code to be suitable. So I guess my question really isn't answered by this.

Comment: Yeah i think that's much more a general issue on how to achieve that with asp.net mvc than specific to ninject. You need a way to define what plugin a `IDependencyResolver.Resolve` request belongs to. You could extend ninject to add a parameter to the "request context" of ninject to specify which plugin the request belongs to, or you could go for something simpler like:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820521/child-container-registration-based-on-route-parameters of course you would not create a `ChildKernel` per request, but rather retrieve the correct `ChildKernel` from a dictionary.